# How to publish web application in Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: iis, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am working with Jenkins pipeline concept. In that, i wish to publish a web application output files into an IIS installed machine(target machine) once the project compiled successfully. For that, i have searched some Jenkins plugins FTP, artifact deployer, etc.. It does not have pipeline support with Jenkins. So, i can't use these plugins. So, could anyone please suggest me the Jenkins plugins which have the pipeline support to copy the web applications output files to an another machine in which IIS installed to publish? Also, please share is there any other way to achieve this with Jenkins pipeline?

**Note:** Jenkins server machine and Publish server machine is different.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Could you use plain shell script?

Answer (score 0):

For that specific job you should look at tools such as [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/), [Capistrano](http://capistranorb.com/) or custom deployment script. It is important to remember to setup everything in secure way and to make sure that you deploy correct version to correct environment.